# Is it possible to set the label name for a none custom field in IFS 9?

Tags: ifs-erp

Is it possible to set the label name for a none custom field in IFS 9?

If I make a custom field I have the option to set the promt and define what label is shown. Is it somehow possible to do that for at field that is not custom made?
Vh. Kresten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just edit the name of an existing non custom field, at least on the front end application.

You could however create a new local or read only custom field that just references the existing field you want to change, and give that one the name you want.

The only way I believe that you could change the name of the actual out of the box field that comes with IFS is to do a modification. Meaning making changes to the application using IFS developer studio like one of their developers would.

Comment: I was hoping that this was not the answer. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Sure. But isn't?

Comment: Found another work around. Haven't tried it, but should work in theory. Go to translation manager in IFS, create a new translation. Like if your translation was english, then create an english2 translation. Find the field you are looking for and change it's translated value to whatever you want it to be. Would need to set that new translation to the proper user's base profile afterwards. More difficult to do than how I made it sound here I think, but it's something. They need to make a right-click rename option.